# Docker Container Creation - mapping from CLI

Tags: docker

I have to migrate the automated creation of Docker containers from a Command Line Interface (CLI) call to a remote REST API (Docker Engine API) call, but I have problems to find the corresponding request body parameters. My CLI call is:

> docker run -d --name itestRun -e LANG=en_UK.UTF-8 -v
>   /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -v /share:/share:Z --network=host
>   --add-host=APPSERVER:127.0.0.1 --add-host=localhost.localdomain:127.0.0.1 mytestimage CMD

I'v found the mappings (-e -> "Env", mytestimage -> "Image", CMD ->"Cmd"), but have problems with the remaining parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker CLI also uses the API to communicate with the daemon. An easy way to find out which requests are made by the CLI is to run the daemon in debug mode, which will log API calls in the daemon logs.

If you don't want to run your regular daemon in debug mode, you can use docker-in-docker. The official `docker` images on Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) can be used for this.

For example, to see the requests for a Docker 1.13.1 daemon;

First, start a container with docker 1.13.1; start the container in interactive mode, and provide `sh` as the main command (this makes it a bit easier);

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /var/lib/docker \
  --privileged \
  --name my-docker \
  docker:1.13.1 \
  sh
```

Inside the container, start the daemon (`dockerd`) in the foreground;

```
dockerd --debug --iptables=false
```

You'll see the daemon starting up;

```
DEBU[0000] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 16
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
...
...
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /networks/prune
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /networks/{id:.*}
INFO[0001] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

Once the daemon is running, *open a new shell*. In that shell, open a new `sh` session in the container you just started using `docker exec`. The example above uses `my-docker` as the container name, so the command will be;

```
docker exec -it my-docker sh
```

Inside that container, you can now run docker commands, and the API calls that are made for each command you run will show up in the output of the daemon in your other shell.

For example, running;

```
docker network create foobar
```

Shows up in the daemon logs as;

```
DEBU[0304] Calling GET /_ping
DEBU[0304] Calling POST /v1.26/networks/create
DEBU[0304] form data: {"Attachable":false,"CheckDuplicate":true,"Driver":"bridge","EnableIPv6":false,"IPAM":{"Config":[],"Driver":"default","Options":{}},"Internal":false,"Labels":{},"Name":"foobar","Options":{}}
```

The body of the API call is printed after `form data:`, and is;

```
{
  "Attachable": false,
  "CheckDuplicate": true,
  "Driver": "bridge",
  "EnableIPv6": false,
  "IPAM": {
    "Config": [],
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": {}
  },
  "Internal": false,
  "Labels": {},
  "Name": "foobar",
  "Options": {}
}
```